# How can we obtain an approximate simplified equation (QsNr) from a set of given equations using Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, approximation

I am trying to find an approximate equation for a complicated expression (QsNr) using Mathematica. The equation involves several parameters and expressions, and I want to simplify it by considering the following approximations: k << 1, Ns << 1, 0<vel<0.5, 0<η<1 and Nb >> 1

**Code:**

```
Xhet = (1 + \[Nu]el)/\[Eta] - 1/2; S = 2 Ns + 1; B = 2 Nb + 1 + 2*Xhet; A = 2*k*Ns + B; Cq = 2*Sqrt[Ns*(Ns + 1)];
vH01 = B; vH02 = S;
vH1[i_] = ((-1)^i*(S - A) + Sqrt[(A + S)^2 - 4*k*(Cq)^2])/2;
vH11 = vH1[1] // FullSimplify; vH12 = vH1[2] // FullSimplify;
G[s_, x_] = (2^s)/((x + 1)^s - (x - 1)^s);
G1 = G[1/2, vH01];G2 = FullSimplify[G[1/2, vH02]];
G3 = FullSimplify[G[1/2, vH11]];G4 = FullSimplify[G[1/2, vH12]];
QsNr = 4*G1*G2*G3*G4;
QsNra = FullSimplify[Series[QsNr,{k,0,1},{Ns,0,1},{\[Eta],0,1},{\[Nu]el,0,1}(*{Xhet,Infinity,1}*),{Nb,Infinity,1}]// Normal]
```

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is known about the order of `k,Ns,Nb`?  Perhaps `k= O[eps], Ns=O[eps],Nb=O[1/eps] eps->0`?

Answer (score 2):

First I assume `k=O[eps],Ns=O[eps],Nb=O[1/eps] eps->0`

If `serNb` is sufficient (see order in Series) to approximate `QsNr`

```
serNb = Normal[Series[QsNr, {Nb, Infinity, 3}]];
```

we get

```
qsNr = Normal[
Series[serNb /. {k -> eps k, Ns -> eps Ns , Nb -> Nb/eps}, {eps, 0,2}]] /. eps -> 1 // Quiet
```

the approximation (With O[eps^2] the approximation includes all parameters `k,Ns,Nb`)

$\text{QsNr}\simeq \frac{16 (\text{$\nu $el}+1)}{\eta }+\frac{8 \left(2
   \sqrt{\text{Ns}} (\text{$\nu $el} \text{Ns}+\text{Ns})-\eta  k
   \sqrt{\text{Ns}}\right)}{\eta }-8 k \text{Ns}+\frac{\text{$\nu
   $el}+1}{\eta  \text{Nb}^2}-4 \text{Nb} \text{Ns}^{5/2}+16 \text{Nb}
   \text{Ns}^{3/2}+32 \text{Nb} \text{Ns}-\frac{2
   \text{Ns}}{\text{Nb}}+32 \text{Nb} \sqrt{\text{Ns}}-\frac{2
   \sqrt{\text{Ns}}}{\text{Nb}}+16
   \text{Nb}-\frac{1}{\text{Nb}}+\frac{32 (\text{$\nu $el}+1)
   \sqrt{\text{Ns}}}{\eta }+\frac{32 (\text{$\nu $el}
   \text{Ns}+\text{Ns})}{\eta }$

**addendum**

reduced order approximations

```
qsNr1=Normal[Series[serNb /. {k -> eps k, Ns -> eps Ns, Nb ->Nb/eps}, {eps, 0, 1}]] /.eps -> 1 // Quiet
(*-(1/Nb) + 16 Nb + 32 Nb Sqrt[Ns] + 32 Nb Ns + 16 Nb Ns^(3/2) + (
16 (1 + \[Nu]el))/\[Eta] + (32 Sqrt[Ns] (1 + \[Nu]el))/\[Eta] + (
32 (Ns + Ns \[Nu]el))/\[Eta]*)


qsNr0=Normal[Series[serNb /. {k -> eps k, Ns -> eps Ns, Nb ->Nb/eps}, {eps, 0, 0}]] /.eps -> 1 // Quiet
(*16 Nb + 32 Nb Sqrt[Ns] + 32 Nb Ns + (16 (1 + \[Nu]el))/\[Eta]*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me with the problem!

Comment: Is there any other way to reduce the size of the approximated expression above?

Comment: @SumitSagar Reduce the order of `Series`, see my mofified answer